# How to run mail function only once?

Tags: php

I want to send mail **(only once)** using php when `$cstt == 10`. I want to prevent sending mail on every time I refresh the page. here is my code

```
if ($cstt == 10) {

echo "Great";

// SENDING EMAIL

$to = "user@example.com";
$subject = "$tracking_id_user is in transit.";

$message =' Hi user, Simple html message. Best Regards!';

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Company <info@company.com>' . "\r\n";

if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)){

echo "mail send";

}else{

echo "email not sent";
}
}
```

Comment: The scenario is incomplete. How is `$cstt` being populated? Unless you store its value somewhere in between requests then it'll always be reset each time (because web applications are stateless by default).

Comment: Hi ADyson,
Thank you for the reply, $cstt == 10 is the result i am getting form a array.

Comment: You could use a boolean session variable

Comment: Ok and how is the array populated? Did you understand the rest of my comment? Rather than just describing, please also edit the question to show relevant code.

Comment: The question is simple on the surface, but the precise answer depends on the context and exactly how the application is working and how to want it to work. As I've already explained, if you want the variable's value to be persistent between requests then you need to store it somewhere and retrieve it. Could be in the session (for short term storage), or a file, or a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the following tasks to achieve the result.

Created a Table `mail_record`.
added `id` and `mail_sent` columns.

after creating the table, wrote the following code.

**Connectin to database**
`$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'user_id', 'password', 'databasename');`

**Accessing the data**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM mail_record";
    $query = $conn->query($sql);
    $row = $query->fetch_assoc();
```

Accessing database to get mail_sent record.

```
// GETTING MAIL SENT / NOT RECORD (BLANK = NOT SENT & yes10 = Sent)
$mail_status = $row(['mail_sent']);

// CREATING THE CONDITION
if($cstt == 10 and $mail_status == ''){

// SENDING EMAIL if $cstt = 10 & email is not sent (blank)
$to = "admin@example.com, user@example.com";
$subject = "email subject";
$message ='Hi user, email text';
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Web admin <admin@example.com>' . "\r\n"; 

if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)){

// ADDING The RECORD THAT EMAIL HAS BEEN SENT FOR ($CSTT == 10)

$sql = "INSERT INTO `mail_record ` (`mail_sent`) VALUES ('yes10')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
  echo "Email sent and record added successfully.";
} else {
  echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
  }
 }
}
```

by adding a if condition / logic we can write a code to execute mail send action only once.

now if you refresh the page the first if condition will give result FALSE because `$cstt == 10 TRUE` but `$mail_status == '' FALSE`.

using this method you can be very sure that the mail will be sent only once.  no matter how many times page is being refreshed.